# How to remove Bullet from draggable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I have one draggable element in my code.

When I am dragging this element the bullet sign appeares, but I don't want this bullet.

Here is my code: `*`http://jsfiddle.net/hirenwebdp/Mf6zJ/333/`*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/337/

I just added `display:block` to your li style. This is the simplest way to accomplish your goal I think.

Comment: This isn't the way to easily do this as the LI element has a list-style and if you do what w3bMak3rs answer you'll be more than satisfied and it is the correct way to do this. Marking this answer correct is foolish.

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this, w3bMak3r's answer is correct

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your css:

```
li.ui-draggable-dragging{
   list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the logical post as I see people stating to use jquerys CSS method when this is not needed at all!!!